# Need help for this regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

```
(?<=[MVAZ])([^MVAZ]*)(?=[MVAZ]?)
```

Hi. I want to match everything from 'MVAZ' characters to any other 'MVAZ' characters not in curly braces. If I do not write any 'MVAZ' between curly brackets, pattern works but sometimes I need to use this characters in curly braces.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nN4oT8/1)

Comment: You can see the stuck in demo. I want to also match all 'MVAZ' characters in curly braces. It is in second line of demo

Answer (score 2):

You may try this,

```
(?<=[MVAZ])(?:\{[^{}]*\}|[^MVAZ])*(?=[MVAZ])
```

This would match the curly bracked block greedily if there is any.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nN4oT8/2)